# Improved approximation algorithm for maximum weighted matching

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I've read the discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203894/a-good-approximation-algorithm-for-the-maximum-weight-perfect-match-in-non-bipar,
and I have implemented the Drake and Hougardy's Simple Approximation Algorithm (PGA) described on the link to get a linear-time maximum weight approximation on my graph.

Reading further, I came upon [another paper](http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/~hougardy/paper/MatchingAlgorithms.pdf) by the same author that describes linear time heuristics which can be used to improve the matching quality:

> There are two simple improvements that are proposed in [5] which can be applied to the PGA algorithm without changing its runtime. The first is to compute a maximum weight matching along the paths constructed by the algorithm and return this as the solution. The second is to add any remaining edges in the graph to the solution until the solution becomes amaximal matching. Neither of these improvements can guarantee a better worst case behaviour for the algorithm, but in practice these improvements can make a considerable difference. Therefore we test both versions of this algorithm. We call the second version where both improvements are applied PGA'

I don't understand what this means at all, or how to actually carry out the improvements. If someone could explain to me in simple terms, that would be great.

Alternatively, [this paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/papers/twothirds.pdf) describes a 'simpler' algorithm which gives a better approximation (2/3 of the maximum weight). This simpler algorithm is still pretty confusing. Can someone explain in greater details how exactly to implement the "deterministic algorithm" outlined in the paper?